# SQLite select data from multiple tables

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I need to fetch data from multiple tables but cannot make a query for that. Any help in this regard will be appreciated. There are some questions already posted about how to fetch data from multiple tables, but somehow i cannot grab the concept behind such query. Therefore i am posting question to ask if someone can build a query for me with the following details:

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,user_name TEXT)
CREATE TABLE category(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT,user_id INTEGER)
CREATE TABLE item(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT,category_id INTEGER)
CREATE TABLE Used(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,frequency REAL,item_id INTEGER)
```

A user may have multiple categories and each category may have multiple items, and each item may have multiple frequency of use.

**I want to select the following:**

- all categories of a user
- all items of those categories
- all frequencies of those items

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you sagi for editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

So you want something like this:

```
SELECT u.user_name,c.name,i.name,used.frequency
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN category c 
 ON(u.id = c.user_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN item i
 ON(i.category_id = c.id)
INNER JOIN Used
 ON(i.id = used.item_id)
WHERE u.user_id = YOUR_USER_HERE
```

Comment: Thanks sagi.
Query works fine but with one exception. There are certain items that have no corresponding frequency in the Used table. I except the query to exclude that, but this query returns a row with used.frequency being an empty cell. Any clue to solve this problem?