# Select data from columns in multiple tables with php and sqlite

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I am creating a login for multiple tables. I have checked some SO answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969558/sqlite-select-data-from-multiple-tables), but I can't seem to understand how this works? Below is my php select statement

```
SELECT export.uname AS exportName, export.pword AS exportPword, 
       import.uname AS importName, import.pword AS importPword, 
       lba.uname AS lbaName, lba.pword AS lbaPword 
WHERE exportName = '$username' AND exportPword = '$password', 
      importName = '$username' AND importPword = '$password';
```

But I get this error:

> Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 17, near ",": syntax error in C:\xampp\htdocs\xport\login.php on line 15

> Warning: SQLite3::querySingle(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, ambiguous column name: uname in C:\xampp\htdocs\xport\login.php on line 17
> Information incorrect

I don't know where the error is coming from because I don't really understand how to select from multiple tables.

If this was one table I could just type:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE uname = '$username' AND pword = '$password';
```

All I am asking is how to do this, but from multiple tables.

Comment: I cannot see a TABLE in your SELECT query and you also have a ',' in your WHERE statement

Comment: There is no `FROM` clause in query but you seem to reference three tables : *export*, *import*, and *lba*.

Comment: where clause is also wrong. you can not use , to specify multiple conditions

Comment: Please if you know how to select data from multiple table please help. I am kinda new to php. If you know any documentation i can read to helpout, i would be grateful